# Mock user with fields to use in a functional test

Tags: 8, testing

How is it possible to mock a user with some simple text fields (for example, *First name* and *Last name*) in a functional test (which extends `BrowserTestBase`) without creating the configuration for this in the config/optional or config/install directory?

Comment: You can create field storage and field config inline during ::setUp() phase

Comment: ... and then create test users for the tests